# Windows Command Prompt, how to move folder?

Tags: windows, alias, movefile

I have a question regarding windows command prompt. I tried to create a cmd file containing simple commands for the use of creating a folder named after the current date , have it create some files and finaly move the folder to a diffrent location. For some reasons the last part is not working right. Here is my code

```
cd Desktop
mkdir "%DATE%"
cd "%DATE%"
echo new > index.html
echo new > main.js
echo new > style.css
```

//move "%DATE%" MeineProjekte <---- thats the problem. Hope someone could help me on this.
And if you have any better ways of displaying this code I would appreciate this aswell

I tried to google for a solution and had not mutch luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `CD` command, you changed the directory. If your `MeineProjekte` folder is not located inside the `%DATE%` folder, you can not move `%DATE%` there.

I assume that you should use `cd ..` after `echo` commands. Something like this:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir "%DATE%"
cd "%DATE%"
echo new > index.html
echo new > main.js
echo new > style.css
cd ..
move "%DATE%" MeineProjekte
```

It will work only if MeineProjekte is in the scope. If not, you should specify the absolute path to this folder (e.g. `C:\MeineProjekte` if it is on your C disk).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your computer does not know if you're talking about a destination file or directory.

You might try the following:

```
move "%DATE%"\ MeineProjekte
```

(The backslash says clearly that `%DATE%` is a directory.)